# Using Scrollpane in bootstrap and override CSS

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, scrollpane

I want to use a Scrollpane to horizontally scroll to a forecast.

I've updated my file and saved it under the name `bootstrap_and_customization.css` in my `css` folder:

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);
#Forecast ul {
float: left;
width: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
list-style-type: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#Forecast ul li div {
float: left;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
background-color: purple;
padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
border-right: 1px solid white;
white-space: nowrap;
}
#Forecast ul li a:hover {
background-color: fuchsia;
}
#Forecast ul li {
display: inline;
/*width: 6em;*/
white-space: nowrap;
}
.border {
border: 1px solid #00ced1;
}
```

I've already added the `white-space: nowrap;` attribute to my elements and to the code itself:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pForecast" ScrollBars="Horizontal" runat="server">
                                <div id="Forecast" class="nowrap">
                                    <ul class="nowrap">
                                        <li class="nowrap"><a>current</a></li>
                                        <li class="nowrap"><a>1h later</a></li>
                                        <li class="nowrap"><a>2h later</a></li>
                                        <li class="nowrap"><a>tomorrow</a></li>
                                        <li class="nowrap"><a>tomorrow and later</a></li>
                                        <li class="nowrap"><a>even later</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </asp:Panel>
```

The markup for `class="nowrap"`:

```
.nowrap {
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

When I run the code it looks like this: 
[image: the menue breaks into more lines]

I'm also using the bootsrap framework and quite a lot other styles. Is it possible to reset them for my div `Forecast` and only use my defined style?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I use Rails to develop my website with **Bootstrap** and I encountered a similar problem where I needed to overwrite some of the styles that **Bootstrap** originally gave me. To do that, I created a `bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss` within my `assets/stylesheet` folder and wrote there my own `css` code.

**Example**

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

$body-bg:                                                   #ecf0f1;
$font-family-sans-serif:                'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
$navbar-height:                                        45px;
$navbar-default-bg:                          white;
$navbar-default-brand-color:      #c0392b;
$brand-primary:                                    #c0392b;
$jumbotron-bg:                                         white;
$link-color: #e74c3c;


.center {
     text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: When I create the file and link it to my page it say that the file was not found (404). When I rename it to `.css` it works but nothing is changed, the elements are still not in the scrollpane

Comment: ok, could you edit your post and add the new file you created along with the page linked the `.css` file.

Comment: Done @Cyzanfar 
I have the bootstrap file locally saved, is there a difference?

Comment: Shouldn't be any different. Are you still having the same issue?

Comment: Yes @Cyzanfar Currently it looks like this [screenshot (picture)](http://picul.de/n5I). The values are filled in the code behind but it breaks in the site (screenshot from an iPhone). (Sorry, but this is a german app, so the values are in german).